# Simple ansible playbook syntax error (YAML)

Tags: ansible

I've just started ansible and have created a simple playbook to deploy nginx on a target server. The YAML playbook file (myplaybook.yml) looks like this:-

```
- name: Configure webserver with nginx
  hosts: webservers
  sudo: True
  tasks:
    - name: install nginx
    - apt: name=nginx update_cache=yes
       environment:
          http_proxy: myproxy.com:8088
          https_proxy: myproxy.com:8088
```

When I execute:-

$ ansible-playbook myplaybook.yml

I get:-

ERROR: Syntax Error while loading YAML script, nginx-ansible.yml
Note: The error may actually appear before this position: line 7, column 23

```
- apt: name=nginx update_cache=yes
       environment:
                  ^
```

I don't see why this error occurs - the hosts file contains the [webservers] section OK - can anyone help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've got a couple problems with your YAML.  First, `- name` and `- apt` shouldn't both have the `-` prefix.  That's making Ansible think you have one task with a name of `install nginx` but no module or anything else associated with it, then you have a second task with no name but invokes the apt module.

The second problem is indentation.  You have an extra space in front of the word `environment` that makes YAML think you're starting a new child element and not just adding attributes to the current task.  So your entire task should look something like this (and remember that spacing is critical):

```
tasks:
  - name: install nginx
    apt: name=nginx update_cache=yes
    environment:
      http_proxy: myproxy.com:8088
      https_proxy: myproxy.com:8088
```

Comment: FWIW I'd probably also use multiline yaml notation as it's easier to read and maintain (e.g. break up your `apt` line to have `name:` and `update_cache:` as separately indented lines)